# Covariance of a portfolio to the underlying investments

Tags: covariance

I would like to calculate the covariance of a three-stock portfolio against the stocks in a ten-stock universe, out of which the portfolio is constructed from. I know the covariance matrix of the stock universe. Knowing the weighting of the three stocks in the portfolio, is there a formula I can use to calculate the ten portfolio-stock covariances?

I use stocks in my example but this question came from an asset allocation exercise involving different asset classes. "Public Equity" is one of the investments in the portfolio and I'm ultimately interested in calculating the equity beta of the portfolio, which is the covariance of the portfolio with "Public Equity" divided by the variance of "Public Equity".

Hopefully this question isn't too confusing!

Comment: Do the stocks have nonlinear correlation?

Answer (score 1):

If the weighted three stock portfolio is $w_1X_1+w_2X_2+w_3X_3$ then I would have thought that its covariance with a stock $X_{PE}$ is $$w_1\operatorname{Cov}(X_1,X_{PE})+w_2\operatorname{Cov}(X_2,X_{PE})+w_3\operatorname{Cov}(X_3,X_{PE})$$ as a result of the linearity of expectation, and similarly its covariance with other stocks